# is there a one liner command make linux go off-grid (cut all network connections)?

Tags: linux, networking

Is there any command to kill all network connections? Ideally it should be reversible with simple command too. So I can switch them on/off quickly.

The closest I can get is `ip link set <interface> down/up`. However, I have different setups which may contain different interfaces. Some have more than 1 Ethernet interfaces. Some have wifi also. I do not want to manually type the interface names.

Ideally it should not affect the loopback interfaces or virtual bridges created by software like libvirt, dockers, etc. So I can still test my local web severs.

Comment: Maybe some kind of firewall rule?  iptables -I INPUT -j DROP; iptables -I forward - j DROP could work for iov4?

Comment: nmcli can turn network connections on and off See https://askubuntu.com/questions/348262/turn-airplane-mode-on-off-via-terminal . To have it act as a toggle (i.e., turn net on if off, and vice versa), see https://askubuntu.com/questions/348262/turn-airplane-mode-on-off-via-terminal

Comment: @DrMoishePippik that only handle wifi ...